# I want pass value from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor))?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass values from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374812/how-to-pass-values-from-view-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-3-razor)

I have this table in database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7CWX.png

And I display all value in 'music' without repitions by this code(View):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(m => m.music).Distinct())
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item, "Deep", ViewData["item"])
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Result:

```
Jazz
Disko
Rock
Metal
```

And I want when I pressed 'Jazz' result was 'Miles','Kirk' etc. How do it? I think I may pass value from View to Controller, but i dont know how do it in my situation. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I realized your problem, you need something like the following action to return the list of users who are interested in a particular genre.

```
public ActionResult InterestedUser(string id) {
    // TODO: return the list of users
}
```

And in the view

```
<ul>
@foreach (var genre in Model) {
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name, "InterestedUser", new { id = genre.Name })</li>
}
</ul>
```

By the way, I can't realized everything from your image, but the `music` column looks a little odd. You might need a `Genres` table.

Comment: This structure genre.Name does not work, becouse I use Select.Distinct in @foreach (var item in Model.Select(m => m.music).Distinct())

Comment: Yep, but it's not important, replace it with the `item` you mentioned before.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't work, I done too in my program, and no working

Comment: My action link is @Html.ActionLink(item,"Deep", new { id = item}), and if I click it, I have error : Perhaps the desired resource (or one of its dependencies of components) is removed, has a different name or is temporarily unavailable. Look at the following URL-address and make sure it is correct.
URL-adress: http://localhost:64270/Home/Deep/Disko%20%20%20%20%20

Comment: What are those '%20' at the end of the url?

Comment: What's the type of `music' column? Is it char?

Comment: I set type 'nvarchar' and 'text' but result all the same this(

Comment: AFAIK, you have to update the current values. And remove the trailing spaces manually.

Comment: Of course, after changing the data type to nvarchar.

Comment: Well, You have to update the available values in the database table. Because sql doesn't remove trailing spaces automatically after you changed data type.

Comment: Mehdi Golchin, thank you.You really helped me!! =)
Intresting, where there are spaces?